# Cannot select EAR 5.0 Server Runtime in Websphere Application Server 6.1

Tags: eclipse, websphere, ear

I need to set the EAR server runtime for my WebSphere Application Server v6.1. I am not able to - I only get version 1.2, 1.3, or 1.4. My coworker uses the same server/IDE (IBM RAD 7.5.4) but sees '5.0' as an option, but I do not. Do you know why this isn't an option for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I wasn't using the latest version of WAS v6.1.

Answer (score 0):

WAS 6.1 JavaEE level is 1.4, I would believe that the problem is on your coworker side. 
See this chart for more detail http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server

Comment: I don't understand why my coworker could run JavaEE 5.0 on WAS 6.1 but not me.

Comment: Are you sure it's JEE5 and not plain Java 5?

Comment: Yes - I'm talking about EAR 5.0